# TeamCity Install on centOS with tomcat5 or jboss

Tags: linux, centos, tomcat, jboss, teamcity

It my 1st time using EC2 (amazon amis) i want install on cent os teamcity and tomcat5, if any one has done please share the same doc or hows to

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jetbrains](http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/07/teamcity-with-lamp-cent-os-amis.html) try this out it will take you 2 hour setup every thinks